# What collation selected for the Spanish language in sql server 2012?

Tags: sql-server, collation, sql-server-2012

What collation selected for the Spanish language in sql server 2012?

Always use utf8_bin in MySQL but in SQL Server is not a choice. the language is Latin American Spanish or any alternatives to utf8_bin?

### EDIT

What is the difference between **Modern_Spanish_CI_AS** and **Modern_Spanish_bin**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In place of "utf8" you'd use the nvarchar/nchar types (which is actually UCS-2 in SQL Server)
This stores *any* character. Although, varchar/char may be OK for Spanish. I know it works for other Western European languages

Then you'd choose a collation (for sorting and comparing) like `Modern_Spanish_Bin`
All Spanish except one seems to use this [says MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143508%28v=sql.105%29). The "one" is `Traditional_Spanish_Bin`

This is slightly different to MySQL where the charset is in the collation and everything is  varchar. SQL Server separates sort/compare (collation) from storage (datatype varchar vs nvarchar)

Edit:

- Modern_Spanish_CI_AS: ignores case so a = A but compares accents à <> a
- Modern_Spanish_bin: looks at the bit patterns only. So a <> A

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143515%28v=sql.105%29)

Comment: you are referring to the data type of columns? like VARCHAR(X)

Comment: all my text fields are VARCHAR, except for some that are TEXT

Comment: @rkmax: I think varchar may work for Spanish actually. Note that text is deprecated for "varchar(max)"

Answer (score 1):

Is `Traditional_Spanish_ci_ai` what you're looking for?

Comment: I do not know. I'm looking for something that has no problems with my language and special characters such as: ñ Ñ á é í ó ú Á Ó Í etc